# vocabulary for protocol dataflows?

Tags: communication, vocabulary

I'm having a mental block for the words describing data flow in a communications protocol + google isn't helping, due to information glut.

In the following scenarios A and B are communicating to each other.

- **command** or **request**: a packet of data going from A to B indicating that B should take some kind of action
- **response**: a packet of data going from B to A in response to a particular packet that A has previously sent to B.
- **acknowledge** or **ACK**: a specific kind of response that just indicates Yes I got that packet of data. (**negative acknowledge** or **NAK** indicates No there was some problem receiving data)
- **{X}**: unsolicited information either from A to B, or B to A, which is neither a response, nor a request for the recipient to take action. Examples: datalogging packets, notification packets, etc.

I can't think of what to call {X}, I'm having a brain cramp.

Also are there other common words in this category? Where would you look them up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not call your "X" just "Message" or "Signal" ?

For some inspiration regarding this subject, may I suggest the [IETF](http://www.ietf.org/) or [ITU-T](http://www.itu.int/) standards bodies.  These two bodies are dominating the communications scene.

Comment: The PCI Express specification calls such things messages.

Comment: "message" works, dunno why I didn't think of it... (hence why I asked.)

Answer (score 1):

I would following the terminology in [Steven's TCP/IP Illusrated](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633469)

So you have a request, response, acknowledement, push and poll are used if I remember correctly